# Type 1 integral comparison with fractions.

Tags: integration, limits, convergence-divergence

Is the following inequality true
$$
 \int_0^\infty \frac{x^n}{x^p + c}
  \leq
 \int_0^\infty \frac{x^n}{x^p},
  \quad
 n, p, c \in \mathbb{R}
$$
in the cases where $n > p$, $n < p$ and $n=p$?

Comment: It's not true if $c<0$.

Comment: @Sambo but is it true for all $c>0$?

Comment: Note that your integral on the right, which simplifies to $\int_0^\infty x^k \, dx$ for some $k$, is always divergent. (Go by cases and split the integral into one from 0 to 1 and one from 1 to $\infty$.) So, it won't be helpful for a comparison test.

Comment: (I guess that in that sense, it is true for $c<0$, albeit trivially, since the right hand side is always $\infty$.)

Comment: What have you tried to solve this problem? And where does it come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the off, as other users have pointed out this integral is unconditionally divergent for all $c<0$.

---

If $c=0$ notice you have:
$$\frac{x^n}{x^p+c}=\frac{x^n}{x^p}=x^{n-p}$$
If $n-p\ge-1$ the integral diverges (this is commonly called the p-test for the region $x\in[0,\infty)$). And for $n-p<1$ the integral diverges due to the region $[0,1]$. From this it is a given that $c>0$ and this will be considered onwards from here.

---

It is worth noting that for large $x$:
$$\frac{x^n}{x^p+c}\sim\frac{x^n}{x^p}=x^{n-p}$$

---

**Case 1: $n>p$**

in this case:
$$x\to\infty,f(x)\to\infty\therefore I\to\infty$$
i.e. the integral is divergent

---

**Case 2: $n=p$**
in this case notice we have:
$$\frac{x^n}{x^p+c}=\frac{x^n}{x^n+c}$$
and so:
$$x\to\infty,f(x)\to1\therefore I\to\infty$$

---

**Case 3: $n<p$**

As mentioned previously, the p-test is the best approach for determining whether the integral of polynomial fractions is convergent when the upper limit is infinity. Once again note that in order for
$$\int_0^\infty\frac{x^n}{x^p+c}dx$$
to converge we require:
$$\int_1^\infty\frac{x^n}{x^p+c}dx$$
to converge. Noting that:
$$\int_1^\infty\frac{1}{x^k}dx$$
is convergent for $k>1$ we now require $p-n>1$

---

From the above we know that the integral:
$$I=\int_0^\infty\frac{x^n}{x^p+c}dx$$
is convergent provided:
$$c>0,p-n>1$$

---

Note that as others have mentioned the right hand side of your inequality is never convergent for any $n,p$ and so is not valid.

I believe there may be a mistake here and the limits should be $1,\infty$ in which, provided the conditions above, the inequality is true

Comment: that's pretty convincing. thanks!! just one more question: from what you stated under case 2, is the implication true that as $x \rightarrow \infty$, if $\neg f(x) \rightarrow 0$, then does $I \rightarrow \infty$

Comment: yes, in effect for an integral over an infinite range to converge the integrand must tend to $0$ (and at a "sufficient" rate!)